# Sentence tokenizer - spaCy to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

Performing sentence tokenizer using spaCy NLP and writing it to Pandas Dataframe.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# Extraction
import spacy,en_core_web_sm
import pandas as pd

# Read the text file
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
doc = nlp(unicode(open('o.txt').read().decode('utf8')) )

for idno, sentence in enumerate(doc.sents):
    print 'Sentence {}:'.format(idno + 1), sentence

Sentences = list(doc.sents)
df = pd.DataFrame(Sentences)
print df
```

output:

```
Sentence 1: This is a sample sentence.
Sentence 2: This is a second sample sentence.
Sentence 3: This is a third sample sentence.
      0   1  2       3         4         5     6
0  This  is  a  sample  sentence         .  None
1  This  is  a  second    sample  sentence     .
2  This  is  a   third    sample  sentence     .
```

Expected output in Pandas

```
    0
0   This is a sample sentence.
1   This is a second sample sentence.
2   This is a third sample sentence.
```

How to achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `pd.read_table(input_file_path)` and adjust the args to import your text to a single column, let's call it df['text'].

Then try this:

`df['sents'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: list(nlp(x).sents))`

You'll have a new column with a list of sentence tokens.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to construct a list and then convert it to Dataframe

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# Extraction
import spacy,en_core_web_sm
import pandas as pd

# Read the text file
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
doc = nlp(unicode(open('o.txt').read().decode('utf8')) )

d = []
for idno, sentence in enumerate(doc.sents):
    d.append({"id": idno, "sentence":str(sentence)})
    print 'Sentence {}:'.format(idno + 1), sentence 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
print df
```

[image]